# ASP.NET Core MVC Web API deployment issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core MVC Web App with Web API, i.e. I have both MVC and API controllers in the same folder.

It works fine on localhost but on IIS when I create a Virtual Directory, the path gets added to the domain.

I can find it using `window.location.pathname`

I can append the 'api/Get' and it works like (`questions` is my virtual directory)

```
http://example.com/questions/api/Question/GetAll
```

But when I navigate to other pages then then controller name also gets appended and then it causes issues.

e.g. if I navigate to the 'Question' page (`QuestionController`), the URL becomes

```
http://example.com/questions/newquestion/api/Question/Create
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/questions/api/Question/Create
```

How can I fix it?

Here is my Asp.Net core api.

```
    [ApiController]
    public class ScheduleController : ControllerBase
    {    
        [HttpGet]
        public List<PathologistSchedule> GetPathologistScheduleByDate(DateTime taskDate)
        {
            return pathologistRepository.GetPathologistScheduleByDate(taskDate).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I call this api from PathologistScheduleController's view using jquery.

Here's the error I get:

GET http://localhost:51434/PathologistSchedule/api/Schedule/?sort=&group=&filter=&taskDate=2020-11-13T21%3A16%3A47.507Z 404 (Not Found)

TIA.

A

Comment: Your problem is in the `window.location.pathname`. Show your client code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have API and MVC projects in one solution you have to config your solution to run multiple projects.

You can use route attribute like this for each of your APIs

```
[Route("~/api/Question/GetAll")]
```

will give you Url `http://example.com/api/Question/GetAll`.

Or

```
[Route("~/api/Question/Create")]
```

will give Url `http://example.com/api/Question/Create`.

And it will not depend on the controller name or folder.

UPDATE because of the question update:
Use this code please:

```
    public class ScheduleController : ControllerBase
    {    
        [Route("~/api/Schedule/GetPathologistScheduleByDate/{taskDate?}")]
        public List<PathologistSchedule> GetPathologistScheduleByDate(DateTime taskDate)
        {
            return pathologistRepository.GetPathologistScheduleByDate(taskDate).ToList();
        }
    }
```

for testing try this route in your browser:

```
http://localhost:51434/api/Schedule/GetPathologistScheduleByDate/2020-11-13T21%3A16%3A47.507Z
```

But basically for APIs you don't need to use any controller or action name. You can use any names you like, for example:

```
 [Route("~/api/Pathologist/GetSchedule/{taskDate?}")]
or 
 [Route("~/api/GetPathologistSchedule/{taskDate?}")]
or even 
 [Route("~/api/{taskDate?}")]
```

The route just should be unique.

Comment: It's not working, I added route this like: [Route("~/api/[controller]")]. I have modified my question to add some code sample. please check.

Comment: I  am not sure that it is a good idea to use : [Route("~/api/[controller]")]. Just for the test,  please try to use implicitly [Route("~/api/Question/GetAll")] for GetALL action and so on. And don' t put any default route on the top of the controller

Comment: I just seen your  new code it  is completely different from I advise you. It will newer work if you don't listen to advise.

Comment: Its the code code. I will try your advice and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your approach but I'm still getting 404 in my local.

Comment: I just tested it in a postman and everything is fine. Did you try it in your browser at least? Just paste my url in the browser url

Comment: If you have API and MVC projects in one solution you have to config your solution to run multiple projects.

Comment: yes, I tried in browser, it works without the controller name only. Yes, they both are in the same project. But it works on localhost without giving any url. Only when hosted on IIS, it adds the virtual directory and it doesn't work then!

Comment: Host it on IIS with the routing I am advising and it will be no difference exept instead of "localhost" will be a domain name.

Comment: API and MVC are in the same project.

Comment: Yes, It is ok. For example  I have a login project. Since it has only several APIs ( to check the password or to get JWT for example) I have APIs in the same project. Just it is a good style to keep them in a separate controller. Asp.net core basically doesn't have any difference between MVC and API . You can use   for APIs  Controller as a base class  instead of ControllerBase, if you need it for some reasons. ControllerBase is just a little compacter if you don't need  an ActionResult.

Answer (score 0):

I added a variable in the 'appsettings.json' and 'appsettings.Development.json' called baseURL and had 'appsettings.json' set to '/VirtualDirectoryName/' and kept the one in 'appsettings.Development.json' as '/'.
Appended this variable when calling APIs.